# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' when i wanted to create django app

Tags: python-3.x, django, pipenv, sqlite3-python

I had a new mechine (PC), I want to use pipenv to work on my django app. It keeps on returning an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'" each time I try "python manage.py startapp " its really giving me issues and I dont know why.

I tried updating python and the pipenv. I also tried installing sqlite3 using "apt-get". Ieven deleted the venv and downladed it again yet same error. I was able to install django and did "django-admin startproject  ." and it ran smoothly. Except when I run "python manage.py startapp " it throws an error.

Comment: `_sqlite3` is not a module....  but `sqlite3` is....

Comment: where is the code ? the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)